# How to take screenshot in jpeg format using ubuntu tools only

Tags: c++, jpeg, screenshot

i need to develope a cpp software to capture screenshot ( in jpeg format ) and send images's bytes through a socket.

I created correctly the server socket but i don't know how to take a screenshot programmatically using ONLY ubuntu preinstalled software.

Using gnome-screenshot:

```
std::system("gnome-screenshot -f screenshot"); // doesn't work from cpp
```

From terminal

```
gnome-screenshot -f screenshot // works but store image in png format ( i need jpeg)
```

Is that the correct tool to use?

is there a better tool that can i use?

Thanks!

**Gnome-screenshot**

```
utente@uduntudev:~/Scrivania/XiboAgent$ gnome-screenshot -f screen.jpg
utente@uduntudev:~/Scrivania/XiboAgent$ file screen.jpg
screen.jpg: PNG image data, 1024 x 768, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
utente@uduntudev:~/Scrivania/XiboAgent$
```

Comment: well to save in jpeg you simply have to specify "screenshot.jpg"..

Comment: no, gnome-screenshot store me an incorrect image and ubuntu can't open it

Comment: for me is working..and it is the easiest way to accomplish it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking a screenshot with C\GTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124229/taking-a-screenshot-with-c-gtk)

Comment: probably you don't have installed `libjpeg` check for ubuntu distribution and install it..

Comment: i have correctly installed libjepg but it continue to save image in png